# daemon process killed automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-plugins, daemon

Recently I run a below command to start daemon process which runs once in a three days.
RAILS_ENV=production lib/daemons/mailer_ctl start, which was working but when I came back after a week and found that process was killed.

Is this normal or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. As far as I understand it, this daemon is supposed to run until *you* kill it. The idea is for it to work at regular intevals, right? So the daemon is supposed to wake up, do its work, then go back to sleep until needed. So if it was killed, that's not normal.

The question is why was it killed and what can you do about it. The first question is one of the toughest ones to answer when debugging detached processes. Unless your daemon leaves some clues in the logs, you may have trouble finding out when and why it terminated. If you look through your logs (and if you're lucky) there may be some clues -- I'd start right around the time when you suspect it last ran and look at your Rails production.log, any log file the daemon may create but also at the system logs.

Let's assume for a moment that you never can figure out what happened to this daemon. What to do about it becomes an interesting question. The first step is: Log as much as you can without making the logs too bulky or impacting performance. At a minimum log wakeup, processing, and completion events, as well as trapping signals and logging them. Best to log to somewhere other than the Rails production.log. You may also want to run the daemon at a shorter interval than 3 days until you are certain it is stable.

Look into using a process monitoring tool like monit (http://mmonit.com/monit/) or god (http://god.rubyforge.org/). These tools can "watch" the status of daemons and if they are not running can automatically start them. You still need to figure out why they are being killed, but at least you have some safety net.

Comment: Thanks for the directions. I went through the log file.